# What does size "1em" in Qt qss mean, if there is no font size em?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets

As of Qt 5 [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) says:

> The supported units are: px: pixels pt: the size of one point (i.e.,
>   1/72 of an inch) em: the em width of the font (i.e., the width of 'M')
>   ex: the ex width of the font (i.e., the height of 'x') However, Qt is
>   limited to font sizes in pt and px and any other size must be in px,
>   em or ex.

When they say `1em` is equivalent `"M"`, which M do they mean? Which font and pt size do they take to calculate that? Based on some other answers I can speculate it is some 12pt font, but which?

The question has a background: Our Qt application has a normal user experience under Windows and Linux, but on Mac OS the fonts appear tiny. If I was able to figure out the relation of pt to em, I could set a better font default for MacOS.

em to pt conversions:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855277/356726) says: 12pt = 16px = 1em = 100% ,[but it also says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855341/356726), it depends on the context (whatever context may mean there)
- Here it gives an approximate overview: http://www.sherriwyche.com/tools/fontconversion.html
- and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19357839/356726) the same question answered.

Comment: "M" means the width of a letter "M" drawn with the font of current context.